# Any risk in attempting to read a key from an object that comes from the user?

Tags: javascript, getter

We're writting an API (node module) and we have the following piece of code:

```
function myFunc(dataFromUser){
    var dataArr = Object.keys(dataFromUser).map(function(key){
        return {name: key, value: dataFromUser[key]};
    });
}
```

Users will use `myFunc` directly, meaning they will pass whatever object they want.

Ignoring how `dataArr` will be used, is there anyway in which at the point `dataFromUser[key]` is evaluated we are vulnerable? Maybe the user can implement a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) in such a way that can hurt us?

Comment: What do you mean, from user directly? Users provide actual JS code that you use without any processing?

Comment: In what way  does it come "from the user directly"? As a JSON string which you parse with JSON.parse? Or as a JSONP import? Or is it exported by some Javascript library?

Comment: I think the only type of data you can send to a server is primitive types, not functions that can be evaluated.

Comment: Well, I can say, we parse _everything_, and based on for what, only allowing a certain character range, and in your case, what else than alpha char would be needed?

Comment: There is no way it can be exploited, it will just access primitive value or another object, getter won't make it through serialization. The question is only what you do with the data provided by user next. But this is out of this question's scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's imagine the following (slightly expanded) function:

```
function myFunc(dataFromUser){
    // ...
    var superSecret = 42;
    var dataArr = Object.keys(dataFromUser).map(function(key){
        return {name: key, value: dataFromUser[key]};
    });
    // ...
}
```

There is no [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), no [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), nothing that you can implement in `dataFromUser` to get access to `superSecret` variable at the time  `dataFromUser[key]` is evaluated.

Not even by attempting to use the `this` keyword, since it refers to `dataFromUser` obj, and not `myFunc`

```js
function myFunc(dataFromUser){
    var dataArr = Object.keys(dataFromUser).map(function(key){
        return {name: key, value: dataFromUser[key]};
    });
    console.log(dataArr);
}

let obj = {stuff:"random"};
Object.defineProperty(obj,"msg",{
    get() { 
      return this; // refers to obj, and not myFunc, even if it is
                   // actually called and evaluated in myFunc
    },
    enumerable: true
  });
  
myFunc(obj)
```

If there is a way the user can hurt you, is:

1. Modify the source code directly;
2. Or, since they will use the `api` by calling `require("your-api")`, to have access to something they shouldn't via the `api` directly.

But through `api.myFunc` there's not much they can do.